# Grunt build useminprepare not working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

I have a problem with my scripts and grunt. I can't get grunt to "copy" my scripts to dist.

So useminPrepare does not include or copy and of the bower_components.

Here is my grunt file: http://pastebin.com/1aFMABam

Here is the useminPrepare

```
useminPrepare: {
 options: {
  dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
 },
 html: '.tmp/index.html'
},
```

HTML i get:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js-->
<!-- bower:js-->
<script src="/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/sifter/sifter.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/microplugin/src/microplugin.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/selectize/dist/js/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/chai/chai.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<!-- endbower-->
<!-- endbuild-->
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/plugins.js-->
<!-- endbuild-->
<!-- build:js scripts/main.js-->
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild-->
```

And my Script folder output.

```
Script
|- Vendor
   |- modernizr.js
```

#### Result I would like

I would like to get every component in it's folder like this:

```
<script src="script/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script/etc/etc.js"></script>
```

BTW: It's not even including main.js!

#### Debug of the task

```
Loading "usemin.js" tasks...OK
+ usemin, useminPrepare

Running "useminPrepare" task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Verifying property useminPrepare.html exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> html
Options: dest="dist"
Going through  to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

  concat:
  { dist: {} }

  uglify:
  { dist: { files: { '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [ 'dist/scripts/scripts.js' ] } } }

  cssmin:
  { dist: 
   { files: 
      { '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': 
         [ '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
           'app/styles/{,*/}*.css' ] } } }

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-09-11 06:43:02 UTC)
loading tasks         246ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 73%
loading grunt-usemin   68ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 20%
useminPrepare:html     25ms  ▇▇▇ 7%
Total 339ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the source of useminprepare, because the src was on .tmp and jade:dist doesn't compile HTML there, it compiles directly to build.